# Python Tkinter: Mi Scrollbar no funciona de repente

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un editor de codigo, y añadi un `Scrollbar()` para mi `Text()`, me funciono perfecto, pero hoy quise añadir una configuracion para que el usuario pueda cambiar la fuente de texto (Fira Code o Consolas)

Cuando añadi eso, mi scrollbar dejo de funcionar, aqui dejo el codigo del scrollbar:

```
window.config(menu=barraMenu)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

codigo = Text(window, height=40,width=105, font=("OCR A Extended", 15),bg= colorfinal, 
fg=colorfont, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
codigo.pack(fill=BOTH,side=LEFT)
codigo.place(x=70,y=40)

scrollbar.config(command=codigo.yview)

window.mainloop()
```

Y asi es como se ve:

[image]
Como puedo solucionarlo? Ya probe muchas cosas, cambiar el width del Text, quitar la configuracion de la fuente

NOTA: Ya he tenido muchos problemas con esta scrollbar, la he cambiado 2 veces, si alguien ofrece una forma de mejorarla, encantado de escucharla

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Lo que pasa es que tu widget Text es demasiado alto. Hay una parte del Text que no se ve, pero está ahí.
El scrollbar se activará cuando haya más lineas escritas que la altura del widget.
Por ejemplo en tu caso el widget mide 40 lineas. El scrollbar se activará cuando hayas escrito 41 lineas o más.

#### Solución

Reduce la altura del widget a una altura en la que todo el Text entre en la pantalla.
Supongo que sabes como, pero ante la duda lo aclararé. Puedes modificar la altura del widget pasando el argumento height al Text:

```
codigo = Text(window, height=20, width=105, font=("OCR A Extended", 15), bg= colorfinal, fg=colorfont, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

[image]

Al no tener el código completo, no se que colores tiene tu ventana y tuve que usar los defaults, pero dudo que eso tenga influencia en el resultado de mi idea.

Comment: Gracias! Tienes razon y logica, muchas gracias por permitir que siga adelante en mi proyecto :D

Comment: Es un placer :D